# Relational query and near - Order by distance - parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

I'm dealing with an issue and I can't solve it, here we go:

I have exactly the same problem as described here, I tried Fosco Marotto's solution (He's a Parser) but didn't work :

https://www.parse.com/questions/relational-query-with-near

My current situation: I have a class ITEM with a Pointer to another class USER which have a field "location" that is a GeoPoint.

All I want is to show all the items near of a given location order by nearest first.

Here's my query:

```
    ParseQuery mUserQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(User.class);
    mUserQuery.whereNear("location",myLocation);

    ParseQuery mItemsParseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(Item.class);
    mItemsParseQuery.include("user");
    mItemsParseQuery.whereMatchesQuery("user",mUserQuery);
```

It works, but items retrieved are not sort by distance

It's possible to do that? Some suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the query against the `User` class is sorted by distance, but it is only being used as a filter to the query on the `Item` class.

If you want the results sorted by distance you'll only get that if you query the `User` class directly. You can achieve this in two ways:

- Do two queries, using the list of users in a `whereContainedIn(users)` filter on the `Item` query
- Add an `item` (single) or `items` (array) property to the `User` class to allow querying by `User` with an `include("item")` or `include("items")`

The only other option is to calculate the distance client-side and augment the results with distance so you can sort client-side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, those are the solutions I thought to solve it but Fosco Marotto's solution gave me the hope to solve it without any changes.
Anyway I'll use the second one approach you suggested. Thanks!